# TIN triangle slope

Tags: linear-algebra

Three points are located in three dimensional (xyz) space forming a triangular 
"surface" when the points are connected by lines. Looking at the triangle in the x-y plane, two of the triangle sides (lines) are at right angles to each other. The slopes of these two lines are known where slope defined as delta z over the length in the x-y plane. How do you solve for the slope of the triangular surface?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for me to do?

Comment: To show us that you did some effort to solve the problem.

Comment: All I could determine so far is that I think it can be solved using linear algebra; however, I am not familiar with working with linear algebra, so I am not sure how to start to solve it.